# Access an Azure Web App from a Web Job using the localhost endpoint?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

If I have a Web App (ASP.NET MVC) deployed in Azure and I also had a Web Job configured to run alongside the web app, my understanding is that the Web Job is an console application (or sorts) that runs and waits on message from a queue.

When a message arrives, can the WebJob call the WebApp using a local address:

> http://localhost:4564/api/myFunc

as opposed to:

> http://mynewapp.azurewebsites.net/api/myFunc

(1) can it be done? (2) Does it make sense to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible for the WebJob to directly send requests to the site via localhost. This limitation is documented on the [sandbox page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#local-address-requests).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that communicating with a localhost without proper set up (described [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox)) may be blocked, i see no potential blockers. But i would still avoid such implementation to avoid any hiccups and go with one of the approaches described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114346/how-to-communicate-from-azure-webjob-to-azure-webapp) in the answer (consider shared storage option).